# Organizing and analyzing logs in an asynchronous Scala web application

Tags: scala, web-applications, logging, asynchronous

In the old days, when each request to a web application was handled by one thread, it was fairly easy to understand the logs.  One could, for example, use a servlet filter to name the thread that was handling a request with some sort of request id.  This request id then could be output in the logs. In this world, a simple grep was all it took to collect the log lines for a given request.

In my current position, I'm building web applications with Scala (we're using Scalatra but that isn't specifically relevant to my question).  Each request creates a scala.concurrent.Future and is then parked until that future has completed.  The important bit here is that the thread that actually handles the business logic is different from the thread that handled the request which is different (I think) from the thread that completes the request and so the context of that request is lost during processing.  The business logic can log all it likes but it is hard to associate that logging with the specific request it relates to.

Now from the standpoint of supporting my web services in production, the old approach was great and I'd like to come up with something similar for my asynchronous services.  I've been trying to come up with a way to do it but have come up empty.  That is, I haven't come up with anything nearly as light weight as the old, name-the-thread model.  Does the Stack Overflow crowd have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have written, assign an id to each request, and pass that to the business logic function. You can also do this with implicit parameter, so your code won't be cluttered.

Comment: This is fine as far as it goes but I think it would actually make the code more cluttered.  Using an implicit parameter for the context/requestId will keep the controller code from getting cluttered but will require me to modify my business logic so it knows about the context and logs it properly. One of the big advantages of the "name the thread" model is that one can then simply include the thread name in the logging format and the business logic doesn't need to know about the context.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with MDC logging available with SLF4j which uses Thread local storage to store the context of the each request.
Also you will have to create a MDC Context Propagating execution context, to move the context across threads.

This post describes it well:
http://code.hootsuite.com/logging-contextual-info-in-an-asynchronous-scala-application/